# How to create a SimpleWeightedGraph<Node, DefaultEdge> from SpanningTree<DefaultEdge>

Tags: java, set, export, minimum-spanning-tree, jgrapht

I used KruskalMinimumSpanningTree so I can use the getSpanningTree() method.
The method returns a SpanningTree only containing edges (no more nodes). For my export Function I need a graph though...
Is there a way to get a graph only containing the Edges from the Set?

```
SimpleWeightedGraph<Node, DefaultEdge> myGraph = createGraph(List<Node> myList);
    KruskalMinimumSpanningTree<Node, DefaultEdge> myKTree = new KruskalMinimumSpanningTree<Node, DefaultEdge>(myGraph);
    SpanningTree<DefaultEdge> mySTree = myKTree.getSpanningTree();
```

My export function:

```
public static void export(SimpleWeightedGraph<Node, DefaultEdge> graph){
    
    DOTExporter<Node, DefaultEdge> exporter =
        new DOTExporter<>(v -> v.address.replaceAll("[ -./äöüß]", "_"));

    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    exporter.exportGraph(graph, writer);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

Comment: If an answer answers your question, consider accepting and upvoting the answer to indicate that your question is answered. If an answer doesn't answer your question, update your question and/or indicate what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming that your spanning tree spans all vertices, you could simply create a subgraph:

```
Graph<Node, DefaultEdge> spanningTreeGraph=new AsSubgraph(myGraph, myGraph.vertexSet(), mySTree.getEdges());
```

If your tree doesn't span the entire graph, you first have to collect the vertices that are incident to a tree edge:

```
Set<Node> vertexSubset=new HashSet<>();
for(DefaultEdge edge : mySTree.getEdges()){
  vertexSubset.add(myGraph.getEdgeSource(edge));
  vertexSubset.add(myGraph.getEdgeTarget(edge));
}
Graph<Node, DefaultEdge> spanningTreeGraph=new AsSubgraph(myGraph, vertexSubset, mySTree.getEdges());
```